# Computer Program more intelligent that the programmer? Is it possible?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, evolutionary-algorithm

Today, I asked a psychologist how can you design an IQ-test to assess a man more intelligent than the designer? He answered me, the same way you can design a chess game program, the designer cannot win it!

However, I'm not sure as a beginner if the question can be answered here, but it is interesting for me **if we can write a program can evolve and learn by itself** such that a human (even the programmer) cannot predict it. I hope the answer to be false, otherwise, there may be viruses or worms in the future with not predictable behavior, controlling the human society!

Comment: No, The programmer along with the scientists must think about the ways future programming languages must be (or hope to be). This worth to ask it here to know how the real programmer think about the weakness of current compilers or tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Artificial intelligence agents behave within some programmed space (a chess-playing agent is inside the chess-playing space).

Agents cannot leave the programmed space. A chess-playing agent is unlikely to take over the world any time soon. It is predictable in this sense.

The behaviour in this space is somewhat predictable (this behaviour is after all based on well-defined mathematical equations) (these equations are usually quite complex, so not easily predictable, but possible), but there is usually some randomness involved, which is obviously not predictable.

Note "intelligence" is not the same as predictability. Researchers have been trying to make AI truly intelligent for a long time, with (arguably) slow progression.

**EDIT:**

Note that some agents can have its programmed space be the entire world. This doesn't enforce a lot of boundaries.

By 'programmed space' I don't mean what was programmed into the agent as much as what the agent is programmed to observe or do. If an agent can only see a chess board and only make chess moves, how will it ever become more than a chess-playing agent?

True evolution may allow agents to extend their programmed space, but I'll have to think about whether this is actually possible.

Comment: I sort of disagree. You are right about the present, and the limitations this AI covers. But if you have an AI who can LEARN by itself, it will evaluate his boundary. It won't be limitated by a simple line of `if (wantToKill == true) { wantToKill = false; }`. The AI will eventually evaluate why people are here, whats best for them and what is not, and decide for itself if it likes the human race or not.

Comment: @Joetjah Think of it more as follows: Animals on land can't suddenly start flying. These are physical limitations on what they are able to achieve. But I suppose they can **evolve** to get wings or create planes. Current AI (to my knowledge) doesn't deal with exploring beyond programmed boundaries particularly well (this may be a result of the fact that it is not true intelligence (well, at least a few people think so), or that researchers didn't strive for this goal).

Comment: It's also more the question whenever or not the AI thinks about it. A camel isn't wondering how to fly over a canyon. We humans do. A few years later we cross the ocean at ten thousand meters height... If you have the intelligence to think outside the box, then you can do anything. Even the humans can, only limited by time (and not by technology as a lot of people like to think).

Comment: after rereading your comment, I noticed I actually typed pretty much the same thing. I guess that's one bug for the human intelligence.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. Chess programs actually do beat their designers by wide margins. They beat the world-champions in Chess by smaller margins but that is a matter of time.

There is an example for a system that "learns how to learn even faster": evolution on earth has optimized itself. Genes and behavior are optimized to facilitate a high rate of marginal improvement. Reproduction almost never fails and genes have just the right amount of mutation due to natural defects (radiation, chemical processes, ...). The "tunables" have been set nicely.

Comment: So, if we can design a program ask questions the programmer cannot answer without evolving, similar to the case of an IQ-test?

Comment: @remo, yes. We can do that with IQ tests already ("what is 466561 * 545641531?") but the problem is that such questions don't tell us much about the test subject.

Comment: Do you mean the time limits the man, but the designer has no such constraint when he is designing the test? Does the time matters?

Comment: Actually, yes! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%27s_law A lot of things have happened, things which people who lived before couldn't imagine possible. Hear someones voice who lives at the other side of the world? See someone's face on a thin screen? Have all the knowledge of the world in your pocket? It's only a matter of time before technology has advanced far enough to develop such robots and AI.

Answer (score 1):

I think your text in the question describes **two** situations:

1. The first alinea covers an IQ-test and a chess-game. Both have a limited amount of options. Even though there are a lot of possibilities, it's limited to a certain number and a lot can be ruled out from start since their use is too low to even consider. Therefore, programs like these exist. Do notice though, there are still A LOT of possibilities, and that's why it isn't perfect yet.
2. The second alinea covers a self learning program or robot. In the real world, there is an infinite amount of possibilities, things that can happen. You might try to code a program, but there is no way (in the near future) you can take amount of all the things life has to offer.

I do have to comment on Dukeling's comment below. If you manage to code a program which can learn to react on pretty much everything life has to offer (including the negative parts), an AI like that will probably evaluate his own 'space' and will be able to look and even step outside of it.

Long story short: it will happen. What its result will be is unknown: either robots are programmed perfectly, or will be shutdown, or the human race will be extinct. Every scenario is possible thanks to the fact we will advance in technology at such pace you can't even imagine right now. Have your doubts? Go tell someone 50 years ago a machine beats the best player in chess.